# Edge element width bigger than screen width on smallest screen size

Tags: css, responsive, microsoft-edge

I have a very basic HTML page

it just has a p tag in with some text

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet libero tristique, vulputate nisi eu, ultricies felis. In pulvinar lacus nec leo scelerisque posuere. Morbi ut fringilla nisi. Mauris sed dui risus. Pellentesque dapibus commodo mauris, placerat facilisis sapien auctor eget. 
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In Edge when you are down to the lowest screen size the text is not wrapping properly (and no horizontal scroll bar appears)

[image]

Is this an Edge bug? Would it happen on Edge on an actual mobile?

Are there any fixes for this?

Comment: is it working fine on chrome

Comment: Actually it works fine with chrome. If you want to fix the issue of scrollbar try overflow: auto it would help the scroll to appear.

Comment: it works fine in IE and chrome for me try use `body{overflow: auto;}`

Comment: The name of the browser is Microsoft Edge. IE is a totally different browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Edge issue. Viewport width in Edge getting stuck at 372px. Chrome and Firefox work as intended.